# Moving/dragging a FramelessWindow? [Qt]

Tags: c++, qt

I have a very simple application that is Windowless (`setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);`) and has one `QPushButton`.

[image]

I made the entire window draggable with the following code:

```
void myApp::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event){
  m_nMouseClick_X_Coordinate = event->x();
  m_nMouseClick_Y_Coordinate = event->y();
  qDebug() << m_nMouseClick_X_Coordinate;
  qDebug() << m_nMouseClick_Y_Coordinate;
}

void myApp::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent* event){
  move(event->globalX()-m_nMouseClick_X_Coordinate,event->globalY()-m_nMouseClick_Y_Coordinate);
  qDebug() << event->globalX();
  qDebug() << event->globalY();
}
```

The window gets dragged fine when I drag anywhere **except** on the `QPushButton`. If I start the drag on the button (click and hold), the `qDebug` outputs nothing. When I start to drag it, the window moves, but the drag origin jumps to the coordinates of wherever the previous drag started and the cursor also jumps to the position of the last drag. Is there a way to make it so that starting the drag on the `QPushButton` doesn't cause this behavior? The coordinates don't seem to get captured when the `QPushButton` is the beginning of the drag.

Thanks in advance.

---

**EDIT:** See the response by @Hi I'm Frogatto below. It gives a good outline of how to do implement this and get it working. I wound up installing the event filter to the pushbutton in the constructor:

`ui->pushButton->installEventFilter(this);`

Then I created my eventfilter:

```
bool myApp::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
  if (obj == ui->pushButton && event->type()==QMouseEvent::MouseButtonPress){
    QMouseEvent *mouseEvent = static_cast<QMouseEvent*>(event);
//    m_nMouseClick_X_Coordinate = mouseEvent->x() + 100;
//    m_nMouseClick_Y_Coordinate = mouseEvent->y() + 90;
    absPosX = ui->pushButton->mapToParent(QPoint(0,0)).x();
    absPosY = ui->pushButton->mapToParent(QPoint(0,0)).y();
    m_nMouseClick_X_Coordinate = mouseEvent->x() + absPosX;
    m_nMouseClick_Y_Coordinate = mouseEvent->y() + absPosY;
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Note that I commented out the section where I update the two variables with hard values. I didn't want to have to hard code the location of the button every time, so I defined some absolute positions of the button using `mapToParent`.

Comment: You probably need to inherit from QPuahButtin and implement dragging for your new class (i.e. register coordinates in mousepress, *in addition* to calling QPushButton::mousePressEvent, and provide mousemove).

Comment: I had same issue. Now problem is that I need TWICE clicking in same position on button to get button clicked. I have not any solution for this issue :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the `QPushButton` absorbs the press event and does not deliver it to its parent widget. So in this case the parent widget will not get notified of that mouse press event. A simple solution to this problem is using Qt [event filters](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/eventsandfilters.html#event-filters). You could install an event filter on that `QPushButton` which could be thought of as an entry point for all events to this button.

Therefore, the workflow is as follows:

1. User presses the mouse click on the button.
2. Mouse press event is delivered to our event filter.
3. Our event filter updates `m_nMouseClick_X_Coordinate` and `m_nMouseClick_Y_Coordinate` variables. And then redirects the event to the button.
4. The button receives the event...

Now, we should do:

- Define our event filter class.
- And implement its filter method.

I will leave the rest to you as an exercise. :)

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for. I almost have it working. I do have one issue, though. I cannot figure out how to update the `m_nMouseClick_X_Coordinate` and `m_nMouseClick_Y_Coordinate` variables from inside the event filter. If I have `bool myApp::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)`, I can't do `m_nMouseClick_X_Coordinate = pressEvent->x();` because `x()` is a part of `QMouseEvent` and not `QEvent`. Any tips? I can set a hard number on the variables (say, 50) and get it to receive the events thus making the cursor jump to coordinates 50,50. But cannot do otherwise.

Comment: Actually, scratch that comment above. How should I be updating `m_nMouseClick_X_Coordinate` and `m_nMouseClick_Y_Coordinate` in the event filter? Using `QMouseEvent *mouseEvent = static_cast<QMouseEvent*>(event);`, when I try to update the vars with `m_nMouseClick_X_Coordinate += mouseEvent->x();`, it assigns a value of what `m_nMouseClick_X_Coordinate` was at the time of the last mouse click and adds the x coordinate of the mouse click inside the button. How do I get it to assign the var of the current press, not last?

Comment: Nevermind. I fixed it! Thank you so much for your guide! Will update my original post once I get it 100% working.