# Proper click event

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, window, borderless

I have borderless form with button like in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35570802/moving-dragging-a-framelesswindow-qt)

Problem is that I can't click button. It works only if I perform double-click not changing position over the button. How to check that user i performing click (not drag)?

Here come code:

```
bool LoginForm::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
    if (event->type() == QMouseEvent::MouseButtonPress)
    {
        QMouseEvent *mouseEvent = static_cast<QMouseEvent *>(event);
        if (obj == ui.loginButton)
        {
            QPoint absPos = ui.loginButton->mapToParent(QPoint(0, 0));
            m_dragPosition = (mouseEvent->pos() + absPos);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

void LoginForm::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if (event->button() == Qt::LeftButton)
    {   
        m_dragPosition = event->globalPos() - frameGeometry().topLeft();
        event->accept();
    }
}

void LoginForm::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if (event->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton)
    {
        QPoint coord = event->globalPos() - m_dragPosition;
        move(coord);
        event->accept();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to check that user is performing click (not drag)?

It should be easier. Don't steal the event from your button. Such approach is borrowed from Qt example: [Music Player](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwinextras-musicplayer-example.html). See [musicplayer.cpp](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwinextras-musicplayer-musicplayer-cpp.html) for details.

```
void LoginForm::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    m_dragPosition = event->globalPos() - pos();
    event->accept();
}


void LoginForm::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    move(event->globalPos() - m_dragPosition);
    event->accept();
}


void LoginForm::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    m_dragPosition = QPoint();
    event->accept();
}
```

Comment: If I do like this and try to drag pressing on button, form will shake as in linked question

Comment: You said the problem is with the click. That example is more of what user may expect from UI. Buttons for clicking and not for dragging.

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest way is disable drag clicking on buttonbool

```
LoginForm::LoginForm(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    ...
    m_isDragButton = false;
} 

LoginForm::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
    if (event->type() == QMouseEvent::MouseButtonPress)
    {
        QMouseEvent *mouseEvent = static_cast<QMouseEvent *>(event);
        if (obj == ui.loginButton)
            m_isDragButton = true;
    }
    return false;
}
void LoginForm::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if (event->button() == Qt::LeftButton)
    {   
        m_dragPosition = event->globalPos() - frameGeometry().topLeft();
        event->accept();
    }
}

void LoginForm::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if (!m_isDragButton)
        if (event->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton)
        {
            QPoint coord = event->globalPos() - m_dragPosition;
            move(coord);
            event->accept();
        }
}

void LoginForm::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    m_isDragButton = false;
    m_dragPosition = QPoint();
    event->accept();
}
```